# Add and bind a new tabpage within c# application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, binding, devexpress

I'd like to add , by code, a new tabpage to my tabcontrol :

```
XtraTabPage resultat = new XtraTabPage();
resultat.Text = "Résultat";
resultat.Name = "tpResultat";
resultat.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(736, 624);
resultat.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("PageVisible", DataContextForm2, "ResultVisibility", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
XtraTabControl1.SuspendLayout();
XtraTabControl1.TabPages.Add(resultat);
XtraTabControl1.ResumeLayout();
```

The `ResultVisibility` is **False** as default,

when I run the application the resultat tabpage is visible!! when i select it , it disappears .
[image: demo]
And when I return to main user control and I try to change the visibility of resultat the binding works, but if I did not select the resultat tabpage at the begining , the tabpage will disappear and  the binding were lost .

So, I need to know:

1. What is the reason of this problem?
2. What is the best way to resolve it?

Comment: Where is the code for hiding and re-showing the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to solve your problem you have to work with property "PageVisible"

```
        var firstTabPage = new XtraTabPage();
        firstTabPage.Text = "first";
        var secondTabPage = new XtraTabPage();
        secondTabPage.Text = "second";

        xtraTabControl1.TabPages.Add(firstTabPage);
        xtraTabControl1.TabPages.Add(secondTabPage);
        xtraTabControl1.TabPages[0].PageVisible = false;
```

[image: Tab page 'first' is invisible]